# Programmatically selecting grid row does not fire itemclick event in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am building an ExtJS4 Web Application and I have a "page" where I have a Grid whose records come from a database. After loading the store of the grid, I want the first item to be selected.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
store.load({
    callback: function() {
        if(store.count() > 0){
            grid.getSelectionModel().select(0);
          //grid.getView().select(0);
        }
    }
});
```

The store loads the database records properly as they're shown in my grid. The first row is also highlighted as if it was clicked. However, my listener/controller for the `itemclick` event isn't firing as opposed to when I manually click the row.

I've also tried `grid.getView().select(0);` as well as `grid.getSelectionModel().selectFirstRow();` but apparently, both those aren't functions.

My grid row appears to be selected by the `itemclick` function isn't being called at all.

Comment: It's the expected behaviour. `itemclick` is for when the row is clicked. If you want to listen for a row being selected, listen to the selection events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use 'selectionchange' listener in **'Ext.selection.Model'** instead of 'itemclick' in grid class. This listener will be fired in both cases when rows are clicked in grid and rows are selected programmatically.

Probably the code will be like this:

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.Model', {
        ...
        listeners: {
           selectionchange: function( this, selected, eOpts ) {
               // Write your listener here or fire another event in view controller
           }
        }
    }
    store: ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. If it helps anyone, do `selected[0]` to get the record that was selected.